# Alternative to aws lambda to run sql query execution to reduce cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

**My case:**
 1. Iam using lambda for connect to redshirt and SQL query execution
 2. using Sam and cloudformation template for this we application 
 3. Generally these SQL queries taking lot of execution time(i.e alredy
    we have optimised queries only). so by this cost will be more for
    single query execution only

**Question:**

- is there any alternate to lambda  to execute sql to reduce cost?

any suggestions?

thanks

---

Comment: Yes there are alternatives - for example you can run the query from ec2 or codebuild - but it depends on your use case. Does it need to be run on a scheduled basis, or in real time for a user request, etc

Comment: this query stored in s3 bucket whenever user select particular query name from UI then that corresponding query  iam going to retrive  from s3 bucket into lambda then i will get connection from redshit using pgdb then in  i will execute this query.

Comment: exacaly what i want is  after getting redshift connection  this query should execute outside the lambda then it's output (in csv form ) should enter into s3 bucket.